# [alert]: fastcgi request record is too big -Fastcgi receives an error message that the get request is too long

Tags: nginx, php, php-fpm, fastcgi, web

> Recently, the program encounter
>   ed a problem, LNMP environment, because PHP in the program spliced GET
>   request uri parameter is too long, resulting in an error, nginx
>   processing uri is too long can be processed by client_head_buffer_size
>   parameter, but when nginx received the uri request forward to PHP,
>   fastcgi can not handle the request error (do not consider changing the
>   request to post).

System：linux CentOS7 nginx：1.14.0 php：7.2.0

Apache solution:

`Add a few parameters to the configuration file 
LimitRequestLine 40940 
LimitRequestFieldSize 40940`

Nginx solution:

`**How to increase the limit of fastcgi to accept uri parameter size?**`

```
user              test;
worker_processes  2;
worker_cpu_affinity 0101 1010;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65535;

events {
    use epoll;
    worker_connections  65535;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
include              mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;
charset utf-8;
sendfile                     on;
tcp_nopush                   on;
keepalive_timeout          300s;
client_header_timeout      300s;
client_body_timeout        300s;
client_max_body_size       100m;
client_body_buffer_size   2048k;
client_header_buffer_size  1024k;
large_client_header_buffers 32 64k;
send_timeout               300s;
fastcgi_connect_timeout    300s;
fastcgi_send_timeout       300s;
fastcgi_read_timeout       300s;
fastcgi_buffer_size       1024k;
fastcgi_buffers          64 64k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size  2048k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 2048k;
gzip                         on;
gzip_min_length              1k;
gzip_buffers             16 16k;
gzip_http_version           1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/javascript application/xml;
gzip_comp_level               3;
gzip_vary                    on;
server_names_hash_max_size  512;
server_names_hash_bucket_size  128;
include /*.conf;
}
```

> Fastcgi error log
>    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzV4H.png
>
> Please Help!!! SOS

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this isn't fixable from only nginx or php-fpm side, but still fixable on the application level, - because upscaling the client_body_buffer isn't really a productive way (but as a workaround you could try, though I advise against it).

Please see [this thread](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,96073,96073#msg-96073).

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem. Fastcgi still cannot receive request parameters greater than 64k.My god.